# Multiple complications in a Android Wear 2.0 watchface

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

How do you add 3 or more complications in your watch face? Does the name of the complication ids matter? I know how to have 2 complications,https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/adding-complications-to-your-android-wear-watch-face/index.html#0, but not 3 or 4.
Is this correct?:

```
private static final int LEFT_DIAL_COMPLICATION = 0;
private static final int RIGHT_DIAL_COMPLICATION = 1;
private static final int BOTTOM_DIAL_COMPLICATION = 2;

public static final int[] COMPLICATION_IDS = {LEFT_DIAL_COMPLICATION, RIGHT_DIAL_COMPLICATION, BOTTOM_DIAL_COMPLICATION};
```

Or do I have to change that code? I haven't found any documentations on 3 complications or more.
Thanks for any answer!

Comment: You can post your answer so it can help others with same problem.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP)*.

The name wasn't the problem, it was a name-array.